# Customer login fails with no message for old migrated (from M1) customers

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, login, cookie, customer-login

I recently migrated a Magento 1.x store to Magento 2.x.

All customers were migrated successfully, etc.

But some customers **can't login** on the frontend **unless they clean their cookies**.

I tried with my own account on Firefox (after cleaning the cookies) and on Chrome (without cleaning the cookies). Only on Firefox worked.

With the correct credentials, **Magento redirects the user back to the login form with no messages on frontend or logs**.

I also tried some variations of cookie path and cookie domain, but didn't work as well. Cookie lifetime is also set to 7 days on frontend, which eliminates timezone problems.

Any solution or idea is appreciated.